# Hadoop Compiled with Different Version than the cluster

Tags: hadoop

If I develop my map-reduce logic with a older hadoop lib version like 0.20.0 and then crated a jar file and run the jar file on a cluster on which the cluster version is higher like 1.0.3 then what will happen? Does the cluster uses the same version of hadoop that compiled my code with or does it ignore what I have compiled it with? Would you please explain how this process work on hadoop in general?

I know that it will run but I see some logs which looks to be the older version of hadoop.common was used. The jar file does not include the lib also.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you'll want to exclude the hadoop-core library from your fat jar, hadoop provides that.

I think what will happen is if you've used any libraries who's API's have changed from version to version you'll get an exception indicating that.

In theory, if the API's haven't changed, it should work, although that's not guaranteed. It's really best to compile and run on the same version.

Comment: I understand that but compile with same version is not an option. The API is the same but logic looks different. My question is how hadoop handles that? I do not include hadoop core lib with my jar but I assume my class path is referencing the core lib that I have compile the code with. Does hadoop care about the classpath file in my jar?